# RaspberryPi & Zabbix server

Tags: server

I was wondering, is it possible to run Zabbix Server on Raspberry Pi @Raspbian? I want to deploy a small freeRADIUS server & Zabbix. I only know, that freeRadius is running 100% properly, but no information about Zabbix server.
Anyone has tried?

Comment: Is it in the Raspbian repositories?  sudo apt-cache search zabbix

Comment: I don't know, I don't have Raspberry yet - I just wanted to know before buying it :)

Comment: I can tell you that it is in the Raspbian repositories but that is the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: @joan you don't need `sudo` to run `apt-cache` =)

Comment: Quite right.  I'm perhaps to used to using sudo in front of apt-get and mistakenly prefix other apt commands.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Zabbix explicitly includes *Raspbian* as a distro target and provides a comprehensive [step-by-step on installing Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=5.0&os_distribution=raspbian&os_version=10_buster&db=mysql&ws=apache) server 4.0 or later on Raspbian.

Comment: You may want to use nginx as the web server - Apache can be a bit heavy on the Pi.  Never got to the bottom of why or if it was just the couple of site running on the 3B but it was OK when moved.